# Display Album Year in Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox

In Rhythmbox songs list, it is showing the columns **Track**, **Title**, **Genre**, **Artist**, **Album** and **Time**. I want to have **Year** field. How to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Preferences/General* and choose which *"Visible Colums"* you want to have displayed:

[image]